# Is there a way to ignore a TypeError (axios get request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Sometimes there is a message that must be displayed to the user. In that case, the message is `res.data.message`. But in some cases, if there is no message, then the `res.data.message is null`. If it's null I get a

> TypeError "Cannot read property 'message' of null".

Is there a way to ignore this error `(if res.data.message is null)` and just continue and don't display anything?

```
getMessage() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        axios
            .get(`/api/getMessage/${this.props.match.params.id}`, {
                headers: {
                    'X-Auth-Token': token
                }
            })
            .then((res) => this.setState({
                message: res.data.message
            }));
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not means the `message` is null, It means the `data` is null.

Use `catch` when you call a promise to handle errors. Study about that.

But you can just use question mark operator like this:

```
.then((res) => this.setState({ message: res.data?.message }));
```

Answer (score 1):

**"Cannot read property 'message' of null"**

Error is because of `res.data` is null not your `res.data.message`

You can change this :

```
this.setState({ message: res.data.message })
```

to :

```
this.setState({ message: res.data ? res.data.message : "Not found" })
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this too. I wasn't aware of that I can use conditionals in setState. :)